# Deploy Workflow into logic app standard: error

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to deploy workflow into my Logic App standard, and I am getting this error:

Workflow 'wwwroot' validation and creation failed. Error: 'The API connection reference name 'demoonedrive' in action 'List_files_in_folder' is invalid. No managed connection found by the API connection reference name 'onedriveforbusiness-3' in connections.json file.'

Definition:

```
{
  "definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
      "List_files_in_folder": {
        "type": "ApiConnection",
        "inputs": {
          "host": {
            "connection": {
              "referenceName": "myonedrive"
            }
          },
          "method": "get",
          "path": "/datasets/default/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('b!GBdMkudITki6B1h2X1w51jihOL.01VM26RYZ'))}",
          "queries": {
            "skipToken": "",
            "top": 20
          }
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "metadata": {
          "b!GBdMkudITki6B1h2X1w51jihOL5Z2BF.01VM26RYZFIKFRJKCUGZVC5": "/DataSubmission"
        }
      },
      "For_each": {
        "type": "foreach",
        "foreach": "@body('List_files_in_folder')?['value']",
        "actions": {
          "Get_file_content_using_path": {
            "type": "ApiConnection",
            "inputs": {
              "host": {
                "connection": {
                  "referenceName": "myonedrive"
                }
              },
              "method": "get",
              "path": "/datasets/default/GetFileContentByPath",
              "queries": {
                "path": "@items('For_each')?['Path']",
                "inferContentType": true
              }
            }
          },
          "Create_blob_(V2)": {
            "type": "ApiConnection",
            "inputs": {
              "host": {
                "connection": {
                  "referenceName": "apiconnName"
                }
              },
              "method": "post",
              "body": "@body('Get_file_content_using_path')",
              "headers": {
                "ReadFileMetadataFromServer": true
              },
              "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files",
              "queries": {
                "folderPath": "/medbills",
                "name": "@items('For_each')?['Name']",
                "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
              }
            },
            "runAfter": {
              "Get_file_content_using_path": [
                "SUCCEEDED"
              ]
            },
            "runtimeConfiguration": {
              "contentTransfer": {
                "transferMode": "Chunked"
              }
            }
          },
          "Delete_file": {
            "type": "ApiConnection",
            "inputs": {
              "host": {
                "connection": {
                  "referenceName": "myonedrive"
                }
              },
              "method": "delete",
              "path": "/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['FileLocator']))}"
            },
            "runAfter": {
              "Create_blob_(V2)": [
                "SUCCEEDED"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "List_files_in_folder": [
            "SUCCEEDED"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "triggers": {
      "Recurrence": {
        "type": "Recurrence",
        "recurrence": {
          "interval": 3,
          "frequency": "Minute",
          "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "connectionReferences": {
    "myonedrive": {
      "connection": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/myonedrive"
      },
      "connectionName": "myonedrive",
      "api": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/id/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/myonedrive"
      },
      "authentication": {
        "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
      }
    },
    "apiconnName": {
      "connection": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/apiconnName"
      },
      "connectionName": "apiconnName",
      "api": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/id/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/apiconnName"
      },
      "authentication": {
        "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}

Here is connections.json
{
    "managedApiConnections": {
        "apiconnName": {
            "api": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/id/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/apiconnName"
            },
            "authentication": {
                "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
            },
            "connection": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/apiconnName"
            },
            "connectionRuntimeUrl": "link"
        },
        
        "myonedrive": {
            "api": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/id/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/myonedrive"
            },
            "authentication": {
                "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
            },
            "connection": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/myonedrive"
            },
            "connectionRuntimeUrl": "link"
        }
    }
}
```